# Custom Routing with OData and Asp.NET Web API

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

So I am writing an API that will return OData but I have a problem with the default routing convention. Due compatibility reasons I can not use the default convention.

In other words, I need to change the routing from

```
/api/customers(1)/something
```

to

```
/api/costumers/1/something
```

Any reference or idea to help me? :)

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention: I am using OData v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking is key-as-segment. It's not original supported in Web API OData. See https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/105

However, you can code a little bit to support it. For example:

Derived from DefaultODataPathHandler, implement the necessary function, enable the UriParser to support KeyAsSegment:

```
uriParser.UrlConventions = ODataUrlConventions.KeyAsSegment;
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: implement the necessary function? what function would that be? None of the methods take a UriParser

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `System.Web.OData, Version=5.9.0.0`, this can be done by invoking the following extension method when configuring your service on startup:

```
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;
...
// This is just to show the type, this will likely come from the web app startup
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
...
config.SetUrlConventions(ODataUrlConventions.KeyAsSegment);
```