# How can I prevent Odata 8 NamingConvention from automatically duplicating my Actions in my controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, odata

SIMILARE BUT NOT DUPLICATE OF : [Duplicate endpoint route on same controller method with OData 8.x and Route attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69288969/duplicate-endpoint-route-on-same-controller-method-with-odata-8-x-and-route-attr)

## INITIAL WORKING SITUATION (simple controller)

I have a simple controller as such :

in Program.cs :
(normal and basic "out of the box..":

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And my Controller :

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class WorkStationsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<WorkStation> Get()
        {
            return _securityDbContext.WorkStations;
        }
 
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<WorkStation>> PostWorkStation(WorkStation workStation)
        {
            _securityDbContext.WorkStations.Add(workStation);
            await _securityDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetWorkStation", new { id = workStation.id }, workStation);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works FINE :

- GET  /api/Workstation  : WORKS! returns my entities
- POST /api/WorkStation  : WORKS! create entity

---

## ADDING ODATA

NOW, I want to ADD ODATA to have the oData filtering/paging/ordering features in the GET(), and the odata results (that contains paging).

So i ADD oData 8 to my .net core 7 webAPI like THIS :

in Program.cs :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
using Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();  //***NEW****
modelBuilder.EntitySet<WorkStation>("WorkStations");   //***NEW****

builder.Services.AddControllers()

     //***NEW****
    .AddOData(  
        options => options.EnableQueryFeatures(maxTopValue: null).AddRouteComponents(  
            routePrefix: "api/",         ///I dont want /odata/...it must be /api/)
            model: modelBuilder.GetEdmModel()));  

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And my Controller :

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class WorkStationsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery(PageSize = 1000)]     //***NEW****
        public IQueryable<WorkStation> Get()
        {
            return _securityDbContext.WorkStations;
        }
 
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<WorkStation>> PostWorkStation(WorkStation workStation)
        {
            _securityDbContext.WorkStations.Add(workStation);
            await _securityDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetWorkStation", new { id = workStation.id }, workStation);
        }
    }
}
```

GREAT!  The GET() will works,  allows querying ($filter, $take, etc..), and the results contains the oData Paging.

**HOWEVER,  I cannot HIT POST ANYMORE!**

I receive this error :

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
>
> MDPWEB_OnlineSales_API.Controllers.WorkStationsController.PostWorkStation (MDPWEB_WEBAPI)
> MDPWEB_OnlineSales_API.Controllers.WorkStationsController.PostWorkStation (MDPWEB_WEBAPI)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.SelectAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidateSet)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.g__AwaitMatch|8_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

---

After some research,  I KNOW it is something about oData NamingConvention adding AUTOMATICALLY ROUTE and use NAMING Convention.

> this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/built-in-routing-conventions

So If I rename my Action from "PostWorkstation"  to "**AnyWord**Workstation" **it will WORK AGAIN.**

> Just like if oData is automatically creating an invisible endpoint named PostWorkStation.

MY QUESTION : How to avoid oData to try adding actions automatiically (if it is the case).

Thanks!

## Ugly solutions i've TRIED :

1 - change every actions in every controllers (20+ controllers, 100 actions..) to remove myself from the oData Naming Convention (every endpoint is named like 'PostEntity',  'PutEntity' etc.....

2 - Add the [OdataIgnored] attribute to EVERY ACtions that I want to exclude (NO!)
-- seen here : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/

3 - Try to EXPLICITELY add [ODataAttributeRouting]  to my GET ACTIONS (method).  But the Post is still 'duplicated'

4 - I checked this question : [Duplicate endpoint route on same controller method with OData 8.x and Route attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69288969/duplicate-endpoint-route-on-same-controller-method-with-odata-8-x-and-route-attr)  but